# sumar días a una fecha en php

Tags: php

Hola muy buenas estoy creando una función para una subscripción donde tengo dos fechas una de registro y otra final de registro pues tengo que hacer un calculo que es sumar a la fecha de registro los días que tengo en otro registro que son los días que dura la subscripción.

```
  public function register_pay(Request $request)    {
      $result=$this->check_usertoken($request->user_id,$request->api_token);        
      if(!$result)    {
          return response()->json(['status'=>'0', 'msg'=>'Algo ha salido mal.']);
      }

      $subscription=Subscription::find($request->subscription_id);
      $totalpay= ($request->duration_day/30)*$subscription->price;
      $startdate = Carbon::now();
      
      $startdate=date('d-m-y');
      $enddate=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($startdate.'+ $request->duration_day days'));

      $success=Quota::create([
          'user_id'          => $request->user_id,
          'start_date'       => $startdate->toDateTimeString(),
          'end_date'         => $enddate,
          'subscription_id'  => $request->subscription_id,
          'duration_day'     => $request->duration_day,
          'total_pay'        => $totalpay    
      ]);

      if($success)   {
          return response()->json(['status'=>'1','msg'=>'Pago realizado de la suscripción.','data'=>$success]);              
      }else{
          return response()->json(['status'=>'0','msg'=>'Error al realizar el pago!']);
      }

  }
```

no si alguien puede echar una mano pues no me sale la función de sumar los días tengo que sumarle a end_date el registro duration_pay que se guarda en días.

Comment: ¿Has intentado con el método strtotime()? Un ejemplo: 

$fecha_actual = date("d-m-Y");
//sumo 1 día
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha_actual."+ 1 days")); 
//resto 1 día
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 days"));

Comment: pero como sumo el campo duration_day es decir como lo pongo donde van los días

Comment: Si ya estás usando una instancia de Carbon, ¿por qué no solo usas el addDays? Mira la documentación [aquí](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)

Comment: tengo que mirar no conozco lo copie de un controlador que realizo otra persona ahora buscare ni idea la verdad gracias

Comment: Si otra persona lo hizo así, dile que deje de arruinar las cosas e invistigue antes de llenar de basura los proyectos.

Answer (score 1):

puedes instalar un paquete llamado Carbon es muy util para el manejo de fechas en php

este es un ejemplo de su uso:

```
 $currentDateTime = Carbon::parse($mifecha);
 $newDateTime = $currentDateTime->addDays(5);
```

Si estas usando composer como instalador de paquetes

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

Comment: La sintaxis del código sugiere que usa Laravel y de ser así entonces no existe necesidad de instalar por separado Carbon

Comment: si pero las etiquetas no lo dicen,entonces si alguien viene aqui sera por php no por laravel